# Rendering javascript after delayed_job

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I need to do some processing on the background after the user has submitted a request. After the job is done, i want to show a message to user that your job is done.

So far i have this

lib/jobs/custom_job.rb

```
class CustomJob

  def perform
    sleep 1 # Here will do the background processing.
    ActionView::Base.new('app/views', {}, ActionController::Base.new).render(file: 'teacher/courses/custom')
  end
end
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Your job is done.");
});
```

controller

```
class Teacher::CoursesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(CustomJob.new)
    @courses = current_teacher.courses.all
  end
end
```

Worker start a job and finished it with no error.

```
[Worker(host:Aragorn pid:3360)] Job CustomJob (id=16) COMPLETED after 1.0635
[Worker(host:Aragorn pid:3360)] 1 jobs processed at 0.9035 j/s, 0 failed
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some sort of polling interface on the front end looking for a complete event on the object on the back end or use some sort of service like pusher.com.

We do this often and this is one of the better patterns we have found which will allow for the user to reload / leave the page and come back to the notice still available if it is still pending completion.

[Possible example to check out](https://www.sitepoint.com/polling-users-rails/)

Comment: Sorry but i did't understand it. I just want to render a javascript and don't think so that some third party service or tool will be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the nature of the delayed job running disconnected from the users experience will not allow you to have a direct response to that user.  Since the job knows nothing about the open sessions and which user spawned the job, you can't respond directly to them.

The easiest way would be to have a flag on the object you are processing in the background and have a route set to check the status of that flag.  Then have the users client polling for that route every 5 seconds until the flag is in a state that shows it is completed.  Then you can respond back to the user.